# Where is Internet Explorer 8 for Windows 7 available?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

I have looked for internet explorer version 8 for windows 7 everywhere on the internet. I am surprised to find that the download page for windows explorer 8 does not list windows 7 as one of the OS for IE 8. Could someone please tell me how to install IE 8 in windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have used one of the Windows 7 editions that allow you to use a third party browser and not install IE8 you can add IE8 back with Control Panel | Programs and Features | Turn Windows features on or off (on the left hand side of the window) | tick Internet Explorer 8.

Ensure you then immediately (before using IE8) run Windows Update and install the latest IE security update (and ideally the other IE updates).

Comment: It seems this is the only option to install IE8 in windows 7 :). Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 3):

IE8 is part of Windows 7 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957700

If it's been removed somehow I would hope that running a Windows Update would give you the option to install it again

Comment: He may have used that Browser Choice thing to install other browsers instead.  I am not sure what happens to IE8 when it is set as the default browser though.

Comment: I totally forgot that those versions of Windows existed. +1